# How to change variable value in Axios response?

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to change a variable value in axios's then. Here is my example:

```
var pts = [];

  axios.get('http://www.example.com')
    .then(function (response) {
      pts = response.data;
    });

  console.log(pts);
```

The `pts` variable just returns empty array. I just want to use it out of the GET query. How can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the new elegant way `async` & `await` it is more neat and readable

```
let pts = [];

 const getData = async () => {
  const {data} = await axios.get("http://www.example.com");
  pts = data;
  return data
}
getData();
console.log(pts);
```

Answer (score 0):

The request is asynchronous so the pts gets printed first and then the function gets called

What you can do is use a promise and make your request as follows:

```
const func1 = () => {
    return axios.get("http://www.example.com").then(response => {return response})
}

func1().then(data => {
    pts = data;
})
```

Comment: Then I'll need to write my codes into another promise. Actually I want to extract this value from Promise.